# Rifle Grip and Hold

Tags: animation, rigging

I am working on an animation in which the character grabs onto a rifle and fires.

Essentially, I would like to know how to have the FK controller move along with the rifle when it fires from recoil, then stopping moving with the rifle when he lets go at the end of the animation.

I believe there is a process involving locators, but I cannot find it. The rifle is parented via object constraint to the right firing hand FK.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, if it's the rifle that moves, maybe parent the IK controller to the rifle with a Child Of constraint?

Comment: Yep, that did it. Could've sworn I had already tried that. Thanks for the help friend.

Answer (score 2):

Parent the IK controller to the rifle with a *Child Of* constraint